# jwPlayer not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jwplayer

For some reason IE8 is not loading the jwPlayer. The jwPlayer version used is: 6.7.
Error: **LOG: No suitable players found and fallback enabled**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="myElement" style="display:block;width:100%">Loading the player...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        width: "640",
                height: "360",      
        file: "/jwplayer/test.mp4",
        image: "/jwplayer/test.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: do you have flash player installed in your system ?????

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062512-no-suitable-players-found-and-fallback-enabled

Comment: Is this issue still occuring ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to the `setup` method:

```
type : 'mp4',
```